# file_put_contents append executes successfully but the file is not appended

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I am trying to log Parsing errors to a log file. Here's the snippet of code that is used to write to the log file.

```
if(!array_key_exists(1,$match))
{
       $result = file_put_contents("$mapdir/$log_fname","\n$link",FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
       if($result===False)     echo "Write failed";
       else                    echo "$result bytes written to $mapdir/$log_fname - ";
       echo "Link error: $link\n";
       return False;
}
```

This returns-

```
104 bytes written to configs/test/log - Link error: FR3.SYD - 10GigabitEthernet5/1 - TRDU PUBLICP|10GE|PIPE NETWORKS|18398|LLNW-00004034 [EQX: NETPROV-981]
```

Which means that the contents were successfully written but when I open the file written to by vi command I see the same file. No content has been added.

Notes-

1. The file I am writing to exists.
2. Permissions for all have been set to 777 using chmod -R
3. I am also writing to several config files in the same location with this script successfully using file_put_contents.

Then why do you think I am facing this problem now with the log file?

Comment: is the Link Error text supposed to be part of the if()? Because you have no `{}` on there, so each branch of the if() only handles one line of code. you put the error message no matter HOW the file_put turns out.

Comment: Yeah, well that was only for debugging. I wanted to print the faulty link in any case.